# Creating an association from an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

The following successfully creates an new association in the memberships table:

```
def create
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  current_user.groups << @group
  flash[:success] = "You have successfuly joined this group."
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @group}
    format.js
  end
end
```

However I would like to test the association has been created first and display an appropriate flash message such as:

```
def create
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  membership = current_user.memberships.create(@group)
  if membership.save
    flash[:success] = "You have successfuly joined this group."
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to join this group."
  end  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @group}
    format.js
  end
end
```

This code however errors with:

```
"ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):"
```

Is it possible to create an association using an existing object?

Answer (score 0):

```
membership = current_user.memberships.create({group_id: @group.id})
```